# Create algorithm with given time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How to approach that kind of a problems? I know the basic time complexities as **O(n)**, **O(n^2)** etc, but how to create an algorithm with like **O(m^2*(log(n))^2)** and **O(log(n^2/m))**?

Is it right for example:
**O(m^2*(log(n))^2)**

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
  for(j=0; j<m; j++)
     for(k=0; k<n; k*=2)
        for(l=0; l<n; l*=2)
            something()
```

What about the second one?

**Edited**: for the second one is just simply like that

> O(log(n^2/m))=O(log(n)+log(n/m))

```
for(i=n;i>0;i/=2);
for(j=n/m;j>0;j/=2);
```

Comment: did you mean `for(k=1; k<n; k*=2)`?

Comment: @RBarryYoung ah yes, thank you! what about the second one?

Comment: Note that **O(log(n^2/m))** is the same as **O(log(n)*2-log(m))**.

Comment: `for(k=1; k<n*n/m; k*=2)` is **O(log(n^2/m))**

Comment: @YairTwito Yes, I understand that it fits like that, but I wanted more explanatory solution (not only one for loop), so that I can understand it better.

Comment: I don't really get the purpose of this, but why not just `for(i = 0; i < m^2*(log(n))^2; ++i) something();` (just pseudo-code) and the like?

Comment: The last loop, as it is written at the moment, uses the same control variable - "i", so the outer loop is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: @PineForestRanch Of course it should be different variable, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth nested loop is O(log n),
The third nested loop is O(log n),
The second nested loop is O(m),
The first loop is O(m)

Because all this loops are nested it is easy to understand that you have to multiply to get the overall complexity  so it is:
O(m*m*log n *log n)=O(m^2 * (log n)^2).

Note that the reason that third and fourth loops are O(log n) is that for example in the fourth loop l is becomes l^2 in the next loop so if m are the overall number that loop is repeated then : l^m >=n -> m is O(log n) .

For the same reason third nested loop is also O(log n).

Also for the same reason if you have :

```
for(i=1;i<n*n/m ;i*=2)
```

the above loop is O(log (n*n/m)) because if you m is the total numbers of loop repeats then:
i^m>=n*n/m -> O(log(n*n/m)).

**UPDATE**

O(log(n*n/m)) = O( log n^2/m) = O(2log(n/m)) = O( log(n/m) ) and not O(log(n)+log(n/m)).

Also if you have :

```
for(i=n;i>0;i/=2)
   for(j=n/m;j>0;j/=2)
      something();
```

This is O(log(n)) for the outer loop and O(log n/m) for the inner loop so overall it is  O(log(n)*log(n/m)) and not O(log(n)+log(n/m)).

Comment: Yeah, I got it. What about the other one?

Comment: how it would looks like with more for loops not directly?

Comment: I don't think there is an obvious way to write O(log(n*n/m))  whith more than one loops. Also keep in mind that O(log(n*n/m)) is more simple O(log(n/m)).

Comment: Isn't something with the decomposition **O(log(n)*2-log(m))**?

Comment: Yes correct it is  O(2logn -logm) which is O(logn-logm).

Comment: so can I write it as a two separate loops, as I can do if it's for example **O(log(n)+log(m))** ?

Comment: NO two not nested  loops would give O(max(log(n),log(m))).

Comment: what about now?

Comment: @Blagch , if for loops are consider NESTED then nothing changed ,Ii NOT NESTED then yes now it is O(log(n)+log(n/m)) which keep in mind is simply O( log n) .